# Multiple subnets through VPN openvpn

Tags: openvpn, subnet

I'm facing the following problem and after a huge amount of trial and errors i could use ask for some help.

Situation:
[image: Scheme]

**SiteA** have LAN network: **192.168.101.0/24** while **SiteB** have LAN network **192.168.102.0/24**. But on a Layer2 switch on SiteB there is an IP device with static ip 192.168.254.2/24.

SiteA and SiteB are connected with a Site To Site openVPN and from SiteA I reach every 192.168.102.0/24 device and vice versa but I don't reach 192.168.254.2.

I created an IP Alias on LAN in SiteB with address 192.168.254.177 then from router on siteB I reach 192.168.254.2 at layer2, but from SiteA I don't reach the 192.168.254.2 device. How can I reach 192.168.254.2 from siteA?

I made a [scheme (image above)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1ejt.jpg) the hope that it will help.

This is a tcp dump on SiteB Router:

```
root@Teltonika-RUT240:~# tcpdump -eni any icmp
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
01:04:29.992742  In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 10.168.101.2 > 192.168.254.2: ICMP echo request, id 54537, seq 0, length 64
01:04:29.993001 Out 00:1e:42:2b:12:58 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 10.168.101.2 > 192.168.254.2: ICMP echo request, id 54537, seq 0, length 64
01:04:29.993037 Out 00:1e:42:2b:12:58 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 10.168.101.2 > 192.168.254.2: ICMP echo request, id 54537, seq 0, length 64
```

10.168.101.2/24 is the SiteB ip on VPN subnet, the openvpn server has ip 10.168.101.1. 00:1e:42:2b:12:58 is the mac address of physical       interface on RUT240 SiteB

The siteB router receives the packet icmp from siteA but is doesnt forward it correctly to 192.168.254.2 device!

Comment: Please, fix things. You have `10.168.101.1` in the part of the description text and in the capture, but other part of the description and a scheme has `192.168.101.0/24` and so on. Better put IP addresses on the scheme on router interfaces where those are configured, that would make it much easier to understand. Also what is default GW for `192.168.254.2` and what are routing tables at each router and all problem hosts (run `ip route` on them)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

10.168.101.0/24 is the vpn subnet. It’s an open vpn TUN (routed) therefore there is a virtual interface on every site with address in the vpn subnet 10.168.101.0/24. 

SiteB have eth0 interface with address 192.168.102.xxx and a tun0 interface with address 10.168.101.xxx.

Comment: Please draw a diagram where each address will be specified near interface it is assigned to, including virtual (VPN) interfaces.